# Is there a way to color parts of the man pages on the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, color

I would like to color some parts of the output of the command `man`, specifically I would like to be able to change the color of the most important things, for example the options or the first introduction to each command.

Is it possible?

I know I can change the color of the prompt and of the output of the command `grep` and `ls`, so I thought we could actually customise more things (if yes, in general, could you please show me a complete guide?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're fairly default and using bash:

- http://www.tuxarena.com/2012/04/tutorial-colored-man-pages-how-it-works/

Short version:
Add the following to your .bashrc file:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf '\e[01;31m') # enter blinking mode – red
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(printf '\e[01;35m') # enter double-bright mode – bold, magenta
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(printf '\e[0m') # turn off all appearance modes (mb, md, so, us)
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(printf '\e[0m') # leave standout mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(printf '\e[01;33m') # enter standout mode – yellow
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(printf '\e[0m') # leave underline mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(printf '\e[04;36m') # enter underline mode – cyan
```

If you use ZSH as part of oh-my-zsh there's a plugin for man-page coloring: [colored-man-pages](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/colored-man-pages)

Answer (score 3):

man can do this on its with less.

You need to set the environment variable MANPAGER

I set it by

```
export MANPAGER="/usr/bin/less -R --use-color -Ddg -Du+y"
```

This works for zsh and bash
The -D arguments set colours,`-Ddg` sets bold text to be green `-Du+y` sets underlined text to be bright yellow.

Answer (score 2):

with the modern versions of less (2021 an later), groff and man,
color output can be achieved by

```bash
export MANPAGER="less --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS --use-color --color=d+g --color=u+y"
export MANROFFOPT="-c"
```

Result:
[image: example of coloured Man output]

See [Adventures with man color](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2021/06/05/adventures-with-man-color/) for detailed explanations